# Is it possible in Java to get text from external Textfields e.g. from WhatsApp or a Chatroom?

Tags: java

I want to do something like a bot for WhatsApp (Desktop Version) that automatically responds to other people's messages, but I don't know how to read the text out of an external program. Is this even possible in Java? If yes, does anyone know how to do this (without WhatsApp API)?

Answer (score 0):

The desktop version of whats app is a web app wrapped into a client app. It is similar to https://web.whatsapp.com. You can use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) to access the HTML with Java.

Comment: I somewhat doubt that you can just inject the Selenium WebDriver into the WhatsApp client.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! It's good to know that it's possible to access the HTML of the Desktop Version. At the beginning, I thought I could do something with the GlobalScreen from JNativeHook or sth, but Selenium sounds quite interesting... Let's see what I can do 